# Bigcommerce Stencil custom handlebars helpers

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to write custom handlebars helpers to use within Stencil templates? If so, where should they be defined? Is there an example somewhere within the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

[How/Where to use Custom Handlbars Helpers in Stencil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580168/how-where-to-use-custom-handlbars-helpers-in-stencil)

All the helpers are predefined that can be used with Stencil "natively". If you'd like to register your own, you'd need to include handlebars as apart of your theme and create them clientside.

Comment: But if I create a helper client side and then use it in a template, will the template render properly if it's done via an Ajax request? Won't the sever version of handlebars not have access to the helper? Sorry I am very new to this concept of server side JavaScript and am having some trouble solidifying exactly how the tech stack is working.

Comment: The server will not have access to this helper. We do not allow custom helpers to be set that render/compile server-side as it poses a potential security risk.